# add KLCalendarView.h in my project

Tags: iphone

I am new to KLCalendar topic. I want to add the KLCalendarView in my project.
I have added the files required using

> link:http://code.google.com/p/scm-subversion/source/browse/trunk/iPhone/CalendarTest/Calendar/?r=11#Calendar%253Fstate%253Dclosed.

is it correct?

And when I added the protocol KLCalendarViewDelegate I am getting error of type:

> Cannot Find Protocol Declaration for KLCalendarViewDelegate.

Please Help me with this issue.